# MIXITUP jquery filter arguments

Tags: jquery

I'm looking into the mixitup jquery plugin, here;
http://mixitup.io

I wish to use the 'Parks' demo, which has the 2 dimensions to filter against.

But if you look at the bottom of the JS the demo uses, pasted below, it mentions;

> In this case, MixItUp will show elements using OR logic within each dimention and AND logic between dimensions.

In my case, I actually require using AND logic within each dimention and AND logic between dimensions too.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone who's used this jquery plugin or can figure it out from the below could help. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        /* 
        *   We would normally recommend that all JavaScript is kept in a seperate .js file,
        *   but we have included it in the document head for convenience.
        */

        // NICE IMAGE LOADING

        /* 
        *   Not part of MixItUp, but this is a great lightweight way 
        *   to gracefully fade-in images with CSS3 after they have loaded
        */

        function imgLoaded(img){    
            $(img).parent().addClass('loaded');
        };

        // ON DOCUMENT READY:

        $(function(){

            // INSTANTIATE MIXITUP

            $('#Parks').mixitup({
                layoutMode: 'list', // Start in list mode (display: block) by default
                listClass: 'list', // Container class for when in list mode
                gridClass: 'grid', // Container class for when in grid mode
                effects: ['fade','blur'], // List of effects 
                listEffects: ['fade','rotateX'] // List of effects ONLY for list mode
            });

            // HANDLE LAYOUT CHANGES

            // Bind layout buttons to toList and toGrid methods:

            $('#ToList').on('click',function(){
                $('.button').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('#Parks').mixitup('toList');
            });

            $('#ToGrid').on('click',function(){
                $('.button').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('#Parks').mixitup('toGrid');
            });

            // HANDLE MULTI-DIMENSIONAL CHECKBOX FILTERING

            /*  
            *   The desired behaviour of multi-dimensional filtering can differ greatly 
            *   from project to project. MixItUp's built in filter button handlers are best
            *   suited to simple filter operations, so we will need to build our own handlers
            *   for this demo to achieve the precise behaviour we need.
            */

            var $filters = $('#Filters').find('li'),
                dimensions = {
                    region: 'all', // Create string for first dimension
                    recreation: 'all' // Create string for second dimension
                };

            // Bind checkbox click handlers:

            $filters.on('click',function(){
                var $t = $(this),
                    dimension = $t.attr('data-dimension'),
                    filter = $t.attr('data-filter'),
                    filterString = dimensions[dimension];

                if(filter == 'all'){
                    // If "all"
                    if(!$t.hasClass('active')){
                        // if unchecked, check "all" and uncheck all other active filters
                        $t.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        // Replace entire string with "all"
                        filterString = 'all';   
                    } else {
                        // Uncheck
                        $t.removeClass('active');
                        // Emtpy string
                        filterString = '';
                    }
                } else {
                    // Else, uncheck "all"
                    $t.siblings('[data-filter="all"]').removeClass('active');
                    // Remove "all" from string
                    filterString = filterString.replace('all','');
                    if(!$t.hasClass('active')){
                        // Check checkbox
                        $t.addClass('active');
                        // Append filter to string
                        filterString = filterString == '' ? filter : filterString+' '+filter;
                    } else {
                        // Uncheck
                        $t.removeClass('active');
                        // Remove filter and preceeding space from string with RegEx
                        var re = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+filter);
                        filterString = filterString.replace(re,'');
                    };
                };

                // Set demension with filterString
                dimensions[dimension] = filterString;

                // We now have two strings containing the filter arguments for each dimension:  
                console.info('dimension 1: '+dimensions.region);
                console.info('dimension 2: '+dimensions.recreation);

                /*
                *   We then send these strings to MixItUp using the filter method. We can send as
                *   many dimensions to MixitUp as we need using an array as the second argument
                *   of the "filter" method. Each dimension must be a space seperated string.
                *
                *   In this case, MixItUp will show elements using OR logic within each dimension and
                *   AND logic between dimensions. At least one dimension must pass for the element to show.
                */

                $('#Parks').mixitup('filter',[dimensions.region, dimensions.recreation])            
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used mixitup before, so I can't guarantee that this'll work, but it seems like what you need to do is use the `filterLogic` config option (http://mixitup.io/#FilterLogic).

Replace `$('#Parks').mixitup('filter',[dimensions.region, dimensions.recreation])` with the below, and it should work for you.

```
$('#Parks').mixitup({
  filter: [dimensions.region, dimensions.recreation],
  filterLogic: 'and'
})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that didn't work, it actually prevented the sort filters working at all. I also tried adding this to the JS page but that seemed to have no effect at all:    


    $('#Grid').mixitup({
      filterLogic: 'and'
     });

     $('#List').mixitup({
      filterLogic: 'and'
     });

Comment: What if you try adding `filterLogic: 'and'` as part of the initial instantiation for mixitup?